# Cannot load html file to another html file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I'm getting a 404 file not found when I try to include an html file into another html using jQuery. Here's my code inside my index.html

```
<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#portfolio").load("list.html"); 
    });
</script>
```

The way my file directory is setup is that both index.html and list.html are within a views folder and being served via a node.js server.

Comment: Try `"/list/list.html"`

Comment: Can you show the contents of your index.html file was well?

Comment: Are you sure `index.html` is in that directory?

Comment: Oh shoot sorry I made a typo. I meant both index.html and list.html are within a "views" folder, not a "list" folder.

Comment: @axlj what difference does it make what is in the file? How does that help resolve a path problem?

Comment: It doesn't matter now that the question specifies 404 error.   Initially I thought it could be a missing or malformed Id.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) explains that you may use a callback parameter on the `load` method, which gives your information about the load request.

```
$( "#portfolio" ).load( "/list.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```

Also, you may check the Network tab of your browser´s Developer Tools to get more information, including URL that your script tried to reach. Debug from there.